# Does Auto-correlation cause AR(p) model?

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

This is the autocorrelation case.

$y_{t}=X_{t}B+u_{t}$

where $u_{t}=\rho u_{t-1}+e_{t},$ $e_{t}$ is iid

From this autocorrelated disturbances,

I might be able to say

$y_{t}=\gamma y_{t-1}+w_{t}$, i.e., ordinal AR(1) model

Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ....

If you have

yt=XtB+ut
where ut=ρut−1+et, et is iid

and you clear fractions then you have a model of the form

y(t)= γy(t−1) + X_{t}-[1-γ]X_{t-1} + e_t$, and  $e_t$ is iid.

where $w_t=  X_{t}-[1-γ]X_{t-1} + e_t$, and $e_t$ is iid.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short. Could you expand it a little?

Comment: This does not look like an AR(1) model to me; should it?

Comment: No ....it should not

Comment: So why is your answer a "yes"?

Comment: YES if you consider w(t) to be not iid

Comment: Thanks!  However I can remember right now that I solved this exactly like your solving before, it reminded me again! In any text as far as I know, I could not find any relevant one, due to uncertainty of w(t) being iid, however if X is fixed, we can get to this conclusion.